# Why are my MP3 files the same size, even when I change the bitrate with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, lame

I converted an audio stream into 3 different settings using essentially the same format. They ended up being exactly the same size. Why is this?

```
ffmpeg -i "Likoonl-Q1-All.mp4" -c:v copy -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 1 -b:a 192k "Q1-All-192k.mp4"
ffmpeg -i "Likoonl-Q1-All.mp4" -c:v copy -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 1 -b:a 160k "Q1-All-160k.mp4"
ffmpeg -i "Likoonl-Q1-All.mp4" -c:v copy -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 1 -b:a 128k "Q1-All-128k.mp4"
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Because you're setting `-q:a` which is LAME's VBR setting. When you use `-q:a`, the CBR setting (`-b:a`) will have no effect.

If you look into the [MP3 encoding guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3) from the FFmpeg wiki you'll find the possible values for `-q:a` with their corresponding average bitrate.

For completeness' sake, here's the relevant part of `libmp3lame.c` – `qscale` is the long name of `q`:

```
/* rate control */
if (avctx->flags & CODEC_FLAG_QSCALE) { // VBR
    lame_set_VBR(s->gfp, vbr_default);
    lame_set_VBR_quality(s->gfp, avctx->global_quality / (float)FF_QP2LAMBDA);
} else {
    if (avctx->bit_rate) {
        if (s->abr) {                   // ABR
            lame_set_VBR(s->gfp, vbr_abr);
            lame_set_VBR_mean_bitrate_kbps(s->gfp, avctx->bit_rate / 1000);
        } else                          // CBR
            lame_set_brate(s->gfp, avctx->bit_rate / 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: 4 minutes to find the source. +1

Comment: I wondered if that wasn't the case! Thanks a lot.